# Find area of triangle in unit circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Hey guys I feel stupid for not being able to solve this, If you can tell me how you got to the answer or if there's something I can read to help me deal with this type of problems it'd help me a lot, thanks!

Find area of triangle BGE in the following unit circle:

[image]

Comment: Can you use integrals to find the area between some lines?

Comment: Uhm I haven't learned that yet, I thought there was an easier solution. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: To clarify your question, do you mean find the area of the part of the triangle that lies inside the circle, or just find the area of the triangle?

Comment: I meant the whole triangle, I've tried to find BG value but I think there's something I'm overlooking.

Comment: What information are you given? Is $\overline{BD}$ horizontal?

Comment: I think we can assume that.  I also think that this is not a sketch by the OP, but a picture from a textbook, meaning he probably deduces just as much from the picture as we do.

Comment: Hint: $BG$ is related to triangle $BDG$, which has a known value $m$ and an unknown $DG$.  Side $DG$ is related to triangle $DGA$, which has known side $AD$ and unknown $AG$.  $AG$ is related to triangle $AGE$, which should be solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle AGE$ share a common base $\overline{AE}$, their areas are in the ratios of their altitudes; because $\triangle BGD \sim \triangle AGE$, the altitudes (and thus the areas) of $\triangle AGE$ and $\triangle ABE$ are in the ratio $AE : (AE + BD)$.

Thus, the area of $\triangle BGE$, which is equal to the area of $\triangle ABE$ minus the area of $\triangle AGE$, must be to the area of $\triangle ABE$ as $BD$ is to $AE+BD$.  Since the area of $\triangle ABE$ is just $BH \cdot AE/2$, we have

\begin{align}
A\triangle AGE & = \frac{BD}{AE+BD} \cdot \frac{BH \cdot AE}{2} \\
               & = \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sec\alpha+\cos\alpha} \cdot
                   \frac{\sin\alpha\cdot\sec\alpha}{2} \\
               & = \frac{\sin\alpha}{2(\sec\alpha+\cos\alpha)}
\end{align}

A little bit of trigonometric manipulation allows us to rewrite this, if we wish, as

$$
A\triangle AGE = \frac{\sin2\alpha}{2(3+\cos2\alpha)}
$$

ETA: This reaches a maximum at $\alpha = \frac{\arccos(-1/3)}{2}$, for which the area is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}$.

Comment: I'm kind of confused but your answer has helped me the most so far, shouldn't the areas of △ABE and △AGE be in proportion to AE/BD?, Thank you very much!

Comment: Not quite.  The altitudes of $\triangle AGE$ and $\triangle BGD$ are in the ratio $AE/BD$, which means that the altitudes (and thus the areas) of $\triangle AGE$ and $\triangle ABE$ are in the ratio $AE/(AE+BD).  (It's currently backwards in the answer; I'm going to fix that.)

Comment: Fixed, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the triangle is right, or goal is to find $BE$ and $BG$. $BE$ is easy using trigonometry (note the triangle $ABE$). The tricky part is to find $BG$.

The angle $\angle BEA$ is $90^\circ-\alpha$. Now, $AE=\sec\alpha$ and $AD=\sin\alpha$. So 
$$\tan \angle AED=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sec\alpha}=\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\frac12\sin(2\alpha)$$

This allows us to find $\angle BEG$ and then $BG$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't advise it, but sometimes calculating everything brings the answer without too many ideas.

To begin with, $$\begin{cases}\overline{BE}=\tan\alpha\\ D=(0,\sin\alpha)\\ B=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)\\E=\left(\frac{1}{\cos\alpha},0\right)\end{cases}$$

The line $r$ joining $D$ and $E$ is $$r\::\:y=\sin\alpha-x\cos\alpha\sin\alpha$$

$G=OB\cap r=(x_G,y_G)$ satisfies $$\begin{cases} y_G -x_G\tan\alpha=0\\ y_G+x_G\cos\alpha\sin\alpha=\sin\alpha\end{cases}$$

By [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems) $$\begin{cases}y_G=\dfrac{\det\begin{pmatrix}0&-\tan\alpha\\\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}}{\det\begin{pmatrix}1&-\tan\alpha\\1&\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}}=\dfrac{\tan\alpha\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha\sin\alpha+\tan\alpha}=\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}\\ 
x_G=\dfrac{\det\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&\sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}}{\det\begin{pmatrix}1&-\tan\alpha\\1&\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\end{pmatrix}}=\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha\sin\alpha+\tan\alpha}=\dfrac{\cos\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}\end{cases}$$

Hence $$\overline{BG}=\sqrt{\left(\cos\alpha-\frac{\cos\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}\right)^2+\left(\sin\alpha-\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}\right)^2}=\\=\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\cos^2\alpha}\right)\sqrt{\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha}=\\=\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}$$

Therefore $$\mathcal{Area}=\frac12 \overline{BE}\cdot\overline{BG}=\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{2+2\cos^2\alpha}=\frac{\sin(2\alpha)}{6+2\cos(2\alpha)}$$

Comment: Wow, fancy!  A little complicated but yes, that should do.

Comment: You might want to explain some of that stuff, putting matrices in trigonometry is not something I've ever seen done.

Comment: Not fancy, really. It's just that I'm not good at geometry. So I set coordinates and do calculations.

Comment: @SimpleArt It's just a calculate-all approach in cartesian coordinates. Not smart **at all**, but in this case the calculations are human.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you for your help and the time you put in writting this answer! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple answer is to use the area of a triangle formula.$$A=\frac12bh$$$h=BG$, $b=BE$.

Another answer would involve integrals.  Its very simple actually, if you can do it.

What an integral does is that it find area beneath a line, curved or not.  You would need an equation to find the area beneath line $BE$ and subtract the area beneath line $GE$.

But you'd be left with a little sliver of the top left of the triangle unaccounted for, so you'd use some trigonometry or some limits to get the exact answer.

You need to use some trigonometry to reach $BG$ and $BE$ for the area formula.

I hope I've helped!  ;)

Comment: I'm in a bit of a rush for now.  I just wanted to provide the method to reach the answer.  I'm sorry if I'm not helpful enough

Comment: That was a very fast response btw.

Comment: It was informative, thanks! I'm trying to grok the other answers

Comment: Thanks.  And did you mean "work"?

Comment: @SimpleArt: "Grok" means to understand thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{15}{67}$ square units, I'd say. I took the equation of the line from O(0,0) to B(3/5,4/5) AND the equation from E(25/3,0) to D(0,4/5); found their intersection G(75/134,50/67); then the area of the triangle EBG. All of these can be done using well-known analytic geometry methods.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on $\alpha$?  Or can you obtain a specific value of $\alpha$ from the diagram?

Comment: @Brian Tung \ Not if you know the coördinates of point B.

Comment: True, but it looks like the $y$-coordinate of $D$ is actually a little greater than $4/5$, the $x$-coordinate of $H$ a little less than $3/5$, and thus the $x$-coordinate of $E$ a little more than $5/3$.

Comment: Well, then you have to (1) ask the OP or else (2) suggest exactly how angle α is to be determined. For that matter, the y-axis misses the tick mark on the circle, too.

Comment: That is not a tick mark on the circle, that is the label $1$.

Comment: Although the diagram is very precise, I'm certain we are supposed to solve this in general based on angle a.  Every line is related to a trig function so all values can be known and expressed in terms of angle a.  And that will give you a method for triangles where B has different unknown coordinates.

Comment: This is truly an instance that illustrates the benefit of using a desktop computer -- as opposed to a smart 'phone, as I normally do, to try to do justice to this interesting problem. @Brian Tung, should I delete?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, myself, but then again, I'm usually against deletion unless the answer is actively unproductive (which I don't think this is).  One could take the approach hinted at here and apply it to general $B(x, y)$ with $x^2+y^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @g-sassatelli’s answer, the area of $\triangle BGE$ is the area of $\triangle ABE$ minus the area of $\triangle AGE$. These two triangles have the same base, so you want to find $A=\frac{1}{2}{\overline{AE}}\left(y_B-y_G\right)$. Straightforward trigonometry gives $$\mbox{Area}=\frac{\sec\alpha}{2}\left(\sin\alpha-y_G\right),$$
so let’s find $y_G$.

Point $G=(x_G,y_G)$ is on the line $\overline{AB}$, so $\dfrac{y_G}{x_G}=\tan\alpha$. Point $G$ is also on the line segment from $E=(\sec\alpha,0)$ to $D=(0,\sin\alpha)$, so $(x_G,y_G)=\left((1-t)\sec\alpha,t\sin\alpha\right)$
for a $t$-value between $0$ and $1$.

Combining these observations, $\displaystyle\frac{t\sin\alpha}{(1-t)\sec\alpha}=\tan\alpha$.

Then $$\displaystyle t=\frac{\sec\alpha\tan\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\sec\alpha\tan\alpha}\mbox{ and }\displaystyle y_G=\frac{\sec\alpha\tan\alpha\sin\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\sec\alpha\tan\alpha}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}.$$ Finally,

$$\mbox{Area}=\frac{\sec\alpha}{2}\left(\sin\alpha-\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos^2\alpha}\right),$$ which can be simplified to G. Sassatelli’s answer, $\dfrac{\sin(2\alpha)}{6+2\cos(2\alpha)}$